# Google maps and Google ReCaptcha GDPR Cookies Compliant

Tags: google-maps, cookies, recaptcha, privacy, gdprconsentform

I have a site which uses *Google Maps*, and *ReCaptcha* APIs; since GDPR about cookies is changed (and now is more complex), **how can I be compliant with new policy**?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Get consent before loading the iframe/JS script from Google Maps & Google reCAPTCHA.

Answer (score 0):

GDPR is not about cookies; the word is not even mentioned. The applicable law is the EU's electronic privacy directive (EPD) of 2002; GDPR is about data protection and raised the underlying standards that the EPD uses. In most ways that matter, GDPR has simplified and clarified what needs to be done. The "complexity" arises from companies that are having to use increasingly obtuse methods to try to work around what they are legally required to do.

There is essentially no safe way to use either Google maps or recaptcha while remaining compliant with either law. Nearly everyone using them is doing so illegally, and hoping that the relevant regulators will continue to do nothing about it. The best way to be compliant is to use a different service that doesn't suffer the same problems.